# Struct Member Variable not Defined - has no member named

Tags: c, struct, packaging, pjsip

I have a struct defined in a file called sock.h:

```
struct pj_sockaddr_in
{
#if defined(PJ_SOCKADDR_HAS_LEN) && PJ_SOCKADDR_HAS_LEN!=0
    pj_uint8_t  sin_zero_len;   /**< Just ignore this.          */
    pj_uint8_t  sin_family; /**< Address family.            */
#else
    pj_uint16_t sin_family; /**< Address family.            */
#endif
    pj_uint16_t sin_port;   /**< Transport layer port number.   */
    pj_in_addr  sin_addr;   /**< IP address.            */
    char    sin_zero[PJ_SOCKADDR_IN_SIN_ZERO_LEN]; /**< Padding.*/
};
```

It is referenced from sock_common.c file:

```
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pj_sockaddr_in_init( pj_sockaddr_in *addr,
                         const pj_str_t *str_addr,
                     pj_uint16_t port)
{
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(addr, (addr->sin_addr.s_addr=PJ_INADDR_NONE, PJ_EINVAL));

    PJ_SOCKADDR_RESET_LEN(addr);
    addr->sin_family = PJ_AF_INET;
    pj_bzero(addr->sin_zero, sizeof(addr->sin_zero));
    pj_sockaddr_in_set_port(addr, port);
    return pj_sockaddr_in_set_str_addr(addr, str_addr);
}
```

It runs into a compilation error which I couldn't figure out why:

```
In function 'pj_sockaddr_in_init':
sock_common.c:error: 'pj_sockaddr_in' has no member named 'sin_zero'
```

My question is how is it possible for a field to be ignored? Other fields in the struct is visible and could be referenced. Any thoughts?

PS: Project source code if interested: http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time, I figured out that the following statement:

```
#undef sin_zero
```

in http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjlib/include/pj/compat/socket.h caused the problem. I am posting this here so that it may help others running into the same issue with PJSIP.

Answer (score 2):

C struct types actually have struct as part of their name. Your function definition should be (based on your struct definition)

```
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pj_sockaddr_in_init( struct pj_sockaddr_in *addr,
                     const pj_str_t *str_addr,
                 pj_uint16_t port)
```

However, it is much more common to just use a typedef in the declaration:

```
    typedef struct
    {
    #if defined(PJ_SOCKADDR_HAS_LEN) && PJ_SOCKADDR_HAS_LEN!=0
        pj_uint8_t  sin_zero_len;   /**< Just ignore this.          */
        pj_uint8_t  sin_family; /**< Address family.            */
    #else
        pj_uint16_t sin_family; /**< Address family.            */
    #endif
        pj_uint16_t sin_port;   /**< Transport layer port number.   */
        pj_in_addr  sin_addr;   /**< IP address.            */
        char    sin_zero[PJ_SOCKADDR_IN_SIN_ZERO_LEN]; /**< Padding.*/
    } pj_sockaddr_in;
```

Comment: +1 in support of this, `pj_sockaddr_in6` in the same header is actually declared correctly via `typedef struct pj_sockaddr_in6 {.... } pj_sockaddr_in6;` It would seem to me the person manning this thing rarely-if-ever builds it on a **C** compiler. It *would* build as-is through a C++ compiler.